# How to have an element follow a dynamic moving element?

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I got most of this done. Here is the code:

```
function gi(a) {
    return document.getElementById(a)
}
gameworld = document.getElementById('GameWorld');
character = document.getElementById('character');
var oldvX = 30;
var oldvY = 30;

gameworld.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var offsetX = e.offsetX;
    var offsetY = e.offsetY;

    var element = e.target;
    character.style.left = offsetX + 'px';
    character.style.top = offsetY + 'px';
});


setInterval(function() {
    monster = gi('monster');
    oldvX += 10;
    oldvY += 10;
    gb = gameworld.getBoundingClientRect();
    cb = character.getBoundingClientRect();

    oldvX += cb.left / 10;
    oldvY += cb.top / 10;
    if (oldvX >= (cb.left)) {

        return
    }
    if (oldvY >= (cb.top)) {

        return
    }

    monster.style.left = oldvX + 'px';
    monster.style.top = oldvY + 'px';

}, 500);
```

And here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g43nxhcw/12/

As you can see, the monster is making its way towards the player via the players' `getBoundingClientRect()`. My dilemma is: When I move around the red square, the monster is not following my character. I am not sure how to accomplish this or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate a direction vector

```
vx = cb.left - parseInt(monster.style.left);
vy = cb.top - parseInt(monster.style.top);
vl = Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy);
vx = vx / vl
vy = vy / vl
```

it always have the length `1`so you can multiply with the step size

```
vx = vx * 10
vy = vy * 10
```

and make it chase you like your little friend:

```
monster.style.left=(parseInt(monster.style.left) + vx) +'px';
monster.style.top=(parseInt(monster.style.top) + vy)+'px';
```

- there is something wrong with your detection of collision also..
  but I wont cover that here

https://jsfiddle.net/g43nxhcw/13/

Comment: ..and the beginning of Monster AI is born. Now I need to sync the positions with my nodejs websocket server :) I removed the ` oldvX+=10;   ` and stuff as well as only the multiple is needed to change speed, thanks Henrik!

Comment: No problem, and true, I didn't bother cleaning it up ;)   - oh - you may want to think about what to do if you have a map for your game, and obstacles are in the way for the monster..

not easily covered in a simple answer.. But it boils down to either path planning, or something reactional like particle physics simulation (giv character and monster opposite charge, give all obstacles same charge as monster, simulate forces, calculate resulting accelleration

Comment: HINT: concerning what happens when the monster can attack you, vl is a distance measure, so you can simply do `if(vl < distance){alert("you died")}`